# ¿Por qué no funciona el comando “cd” en un script de bash?

Tags: bash, shell

> **Pregunta original**: [Why doesn't “cd” work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script) de [ashokgelal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33203/ashokgelal)

Si creo un script como el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd otro-directorio
echo "Cambie de directorio!"
pwd
```

Y lo ejecuto en la consola, el script reporta estar en otro directorio. Pero cuando recupero el control de la consola el cambio fue deshecho:

```
$ pwd
/home/usuario/
$ cat mi_script
#!/bin/bash
cd otro-directorio
$ ./mi_script
$ pwd
Cambie de directorio
/home/usuario/otro-directorio
$ pwd
/home/usuario/
```

¿Por qué ocurre esto? ¿Por qué el cambio de directorio se deshace al salir del script?

Comment: ¡Pero falta la pregunta original! Estás preguntando con una respuesta

Comment: No lo estás haciendo bien, porque estás mezclando la respuesta con la pregunta. Por favor, si vas a hacer una traducción sepáralas.

Comment: @CésarBustíos por 6 segundos :P

Comment: @astrojuanlu jejeje justo andaba flojeando en el trabajo :P

Comment: Ahí reordené la pregunta y respuesta.

Comment: Dar votos negativos a lo exagerado es como querer hundir a alguien que tiene ganas de nadar y no enseñarle, es egoísta.

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas traducidas no agregan valor a la comunidad

Comment: @JuanK, ¿por qué considerás que explicar cómo funcionan `cd` y las subshells no agregan valor a es.SO pero sí lo aportan en en.SO?

Comment: Ahora que Carlos Muñoz ha editado la pregunta ya está bien formulada, he votado para que se reabra. Reconsideren sus negativos, por favor.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia No soy amigo de promover la comunidad de SO español traduciendo aportes que vienen de SO en inglés. y que valga decir allí han acumulado cientos de Upovotes. Prefiero que las preguntas surjan aquí de manera legítima. Traer las preguntas populares de SO solo es conveniente para quien las trae porque acumulará puntos y privilegios rápidamente. No encontré otra forma de  más adecuada de ponerlo en cola de cierre, de las disponibles poner la de "no esta claro" fue la mejor. Pero deje alli mis comentarios.

Comment: @JuanK: leo en tu mensaje que preferís que cierren una pregunta que más de uno puede hacerse, porque es una copia de un sitio que alienta a ser copiado, antes que dar la posibilidad a alguien de encontrar fácilmente la respuesta a esa pregunta. Siento que tus prioridades no son las que quiero para el sitio, y creo que efectivamente no son las del sitio - aunque no tenga evidencia dura en la que basarme.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia Bueno es un tema que ya ha sido discutido en meta, te invito a que lo discutas allí si así lo prefieres. Las respuestas traducidas se van para wiki . Lamentablemente por loable que parezca este tipo de aportes son más para minería de puntos y privilegios que por aportar a la comunidad.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia los lineamientos más recientes al respecto aquí http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/237/398

Answer (score 3):

> Respuesta original adaptada de [Why doesn't “cd” work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script/255415#255415) de [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) traducida por [dabellan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2222/dabellan)

El script se ejecuta en un **subproceso** por lo que tiene su propio ámbito de trabajo (por defecto, el directorio inicial es el del proceso padre).

El comando `cd` **funciona correctamente**, solo que el directorio **cambia solo en el ámbito del subproceso creado**: en cuanto termina la ejecución del script, el proceso del mismo finaliza y volvemos al proceso de la shell. Como la shell *nunca cambió* de directorio, sigue estando en el directorio original - y por eso da la sensación de que se deshizo el cambio.

Comment: ¿Hay algo malo en la respuesta?

Comment: Probablemente no, pero la gente se pone demsaiado especial con las preguntas y respuestas traducidas a veces, te recomiendo que conviertas la respuesta en wiki de la comunidad para evitarte los votos negativos

Comment: No hay nada malo, pero tanto la pregunta como la respuesta son copias de SO en ingles. De mi parte he recomendado convertir ambas a wiki ya que no hay aporte técnico (no se si se pueda en la pregunta)

Answer (score 2):

Para explicarlo he modificado ligeramente tu script. He creado un archivo a.txt dentro del directorio otro-directorio; ese archivo no existe en el directorio en que inicio la prueba.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd otro-directorio
echo "Cambie de directorio!"
cat a.txt
pwd
ps ax | grep bash | grep -v grep
```

Abro una terminal con bash, y ejecuto los comandos que ves a continuación incluyendo ese script :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que ocurre en un sistema UNIX (y sucede algo similar en otros sistemas) cuando abro una terminal bash es que se lanza un proceso bash, que en este caso tiene el identificador 7546.
Todos los procesos tienen varios elementos comunes, entre ellos un directorio actual.

Como podemos ver con el comando `ps` hay un solo proceso llamado bash en ejecución al empezar.

Al ejecutar `mi_script.sh` lo que hace bash es una llamada de sistema `fork()` la cual crea otro proceso hijo (el 7971) y es sobre este proceso sobre el que se ejecuta el script. Este proceso como todos los procesos tiene su particulare directorio actual. Al crearse el proceso hereda el directorio actual y la salida estandard de su padre (el 7546), por eso empieza en el mismo directorio que estaba su padre y por eso su salida sale por el mismo sitio que en el padre.

Al ejecutar `cd` cambiamos el directorio actual del proceso 7971. Pero esto no afecta a ningún otro proceso. Por eso el proceso 7546 sigue estando en el mismo directorio que estaba.
El cambio sí que tiene efectos sobre 7971, como podemos ver en el hecho de que muestra el contenido del archivo /home/test/otro-directorio/a.txt.
Cuando hacemos ps desde el proceso 7971 podemos ver que hay dos procesos bash, el hijo(7971) y el padre(7546). Este último ha ejecutado `wait(int* status)` y está esperando a que el hijo termine.

Cuando el proceso bash hijo termina su trabajo llama a `exit(int)`, el sistema operativo destruye el proceso y el padre se entera al acabar `wait` y continua su ejecución. Su directorio actual sigue siendo /home/test.

**Para cambiar el directorio actual sin lanzar otro proceso usa un alias**
Edita tu fichero .bashrc y añade esta línea :

```
alias cdo='cd /home/test/otro-directorio'
```

.bashrc se carga cada vez que lanzas un terminal bash. Escribiendo el alias cdo cambiarás a ese directorio sin lanzar otro proceso bash.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno como te han dicho muchos , es porque se ejectura en el subproceso del padre, para poder ejecutarlo en el proceso del padre directamente , al ejecutarlo utiliza source

Ejemplo:

```
$source script
```